# PhoneGap, jQuery getJSON and CORS

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, cors

I'm developing a mobile application based on PhoneGap. I need to use AJAX, I'm working with jQuery.

I'm trying to get a JSON from a WS on PHP with CORS, but I get an error, and the error message is empty. I tested the code in a Web Browser and it works. But, when I used it with PhoneGap it did not worked. I tested my code in PhoneGAp with Fecebook WS and it works. This is the combination that I tested:

Test 1
Source: file:///C:/.../index.html (Web Browser)
WebService: http: //localhost/.../getemployees.php
Result: it works

Test 2
Source: PhoneGap
WebService: http: //localhost/.../getemployees.php
Result: it does not works

Test 3
Source: PhoneGap
WebService: https: //graph.facebook.com/OldemarshCr
Result: it works

This is the code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {console.log(data);})
.success(function() { console.log("second success"); })
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log('******* '+"error: " + textStatus+' *******');
});
```

This is the JSON response:

```
{"items":[{"id":"10","firstName":"Kathleen","lastName":"Byrne","title":"Sales Representative","picture":"kathleen_byrne.jpg","reportCount":"0"},{"id":"9","firstName":"Gary","lastName":"Donovan","title":"Marketing","picture":"gary_donovan.jpg","reportCount":"0"},{"id":"7","firstName":"Paula","lastName":"Gates","title":"Software Architect","picture":"paula_gates.jpg","reportCount":"0"]}
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you use andoid emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call, try and add

```
         $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,                 
                xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
              });
```

Comment: I'm not using the ajax method, but I will try with it

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax did not work... this is the error that I get

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I tested the code on web browser and it worked.

This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,  
  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
  type: 'GET', 
  url: url, 
  dataType: 'json', 
  success: function(response){ console.log(response); }
  error: function(error){ console.log('Error: '+error); }
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Good News!!

I solved the problem. Both methods, getJSON and ajax, are working, the problem was the server.

When I accessed the Web Services from a external server (not localhost) it worked.

Thanks,